# Excel VBA Array For Each Unique Values

Tags: arrays, excel, vba, foreach

i try to create an array and fill it with unique values.
Due to check if the value is unique, i fail to create a basic "for each" procedure.
I just want to create a unique random number, put it into an array, create another unique random number an put it into the same array.
If fail into search about that topic and failed to google that problem, therefore i have to ask the community at stackoverlofw.

I dont have any valuable code because nothing worked.

I only have an google code which worked for me in cells at excel, but not in array.

```
For Each Cell In Selection.Cells

    Do
        rndNumber = Int((High - Low + 1) * Rnd() + Low)
    Loop Until Selection.Cells.Find(rndNumber, LookIn:=xlValues, LookAt:=xlWhole) Is Nothing
    Cell.Value = rndNumber
Next
```

Hopefully

Comment: You might want to use a `Scripting.Dictionary` as the container with the random numbers as keys.  If you need to use it in array form, just dump out the `.Keys` array.

Comment: In which constellation the container is used for that kind of problem?
In my optionon it has to be a easy going to solve that problem with just "for each" and "do - loop until" utilities excel vba is providing.

Comment: luckily for you, excel would crash way before you'd have enough random numbers to expect a duplicate. Just fill an array with random numbers, don't worry about the duplicates.

Comment: @Andrew - Huh?  I'm not sure I understand your question.

Comment: @ Comintern
Okay:
I have an array. This array has a range of x (not important for this task)
Let this array be a 1 dimensional array with x numbers.
This array have to be filled with random unique numbers.
Question: hove to made it in excel vba with unique numbers :)

Comment: I'll reiterate.  Use a `Scripting.Dictionary`.  If `.Exists` returns `True`, try a new number.  If `.Exists` is `False`, add it as the key.  If you need the container to be an array, dump one out with the `Keys` function.  I thought the first comment was fairly clear.

Comment: @Comintern - I would just write the keys, overwriting any duplicates until `dict.count = 10`

Comment: @Jeeped - Certainly easier.  ;-)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
Option Explicit

Function GetRandomsArray(ByVal n As Long, Low As Long, High As Long)
    Dim rndNumber As Long

    If High - Low + 1 < n Then n = High - Low + 1
    With CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
        Do
            rndNumber = Int((High - Low + 1) * Rnd() + Low)
            .Item(rndNumber) = 1
        Loop While .Count < n
        GetRandomsArray = .Keys
    End With
End Function
```

To be used in a "Main" sub as follows:

```
Dim myArray As Variant

myArray = GetRandomsArray(5, 1, 10) '<--| get an array of 5 unique random numbers between 1 and 10
```

Comment: Ooookay
This works for me, but i dont know why :D
Thank you for this example! I have to understand your code step by step cause i dont want to use some code without understanding it. But just to be sure: thanks!

Comment: You are welcome. As per @Comintern suggestion it uses a Dictionary object that doesn't allow for duplicate keys so it iterates as long as it needs to sum up n items. Then it dumps those keys out in an array. BTW you may want to mark this answer as accepted. Thank you!

Comment: @Andrew - See [Scripting.Dictionary object - Properties and Methods](http://stackoverflow.com/documentation/vba/3667/scripting-dictionary-object/12617/properties-and-methods#t=201702272300313008366) in StackOvedrflow's VBA documentation.